# On dublicate key Ошибка Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = "INSERT INTO actual_amo_columns 
(pipeline_name, status_id, status_name) 
VALUES ('$pipelinename', '$statusid', '$statusname')
ON DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`pipeline_name` = VALUES('$pipelinename'),
`status_id` = VALUES('$statusid'), 
`status_name` = VALUES('$statusname')";

$query_result = mysqli_query($dbcnx,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbcnx));
```

Не пойму, что не нравится то ему?

> for the right syntax to use near 'DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE `pipeline_name` = VALUES('PIPELINE1'),`status_id` = VAL' at line 2

Может значения не могут быть пустыми? Как тогда изменить запрос?

А если делаю `ON DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE`pipeline_name`= '$pipelinename'`, 
то записи дублируются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сверяйте с мануалам по буквам: [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Вы написали неверно, потому и закономерный syntax error.

Comment: Да, сдуру. Но теперь новая ошибка 
for the right syntax to use near ''PIPELINE1'),`status_id` = VALUES('123123'), `status_name` = VALUES('Не' at line 2

Comment: выведите на экран отправляемый запрос и смотрите на него. mysql рапортует ошибку с того места где дальше по синтаксису такого быть не может. У вас похоже на банальный sql injection.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO actual_amo_columns (pipeline_name, status_id, status_name) VALUES ('PIPELINE.RU', '28235989', 'Неразобранное')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `pipeline_name` = VALUES('PIPELINE.RU'),`status_id` = VALUES('28235989'), `status_name` = VALUES('Неразобранное')"`

https://i.gyazo.com/4f302c151fab74e5fd51d69b6d7028ea.png

Вроде всё чисто

Comment: нет идей что сейчас не так?

Comment: @theblackpost Как что? аргументом функции VALUES() должно быть имя поля. А не подозрительный строковый литерал. Кавычки убери, да... Или, если это значение, которое должно быть записано в поле - то функция VALUES() тут нафиг не нужна, просто присваивай литерал.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO actual_amo_columns (pipeline_name, status_id, status_name) VALUES ('$pipelinename', '$statusid', '$statusname')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `pipeline_name` = VALUES(`pipeline_name`),`status_id` = VALUES(`status_id`), `status_name` = VALUES(`status_name`)";` 

Поправил, но записи дублируются, при каждом запуске запроса создаётся дубль.

SELECT COUNT(`status_id`)
FROM `actual_amo_columns`
WHERE `status_id` = '30672256'

COUNT(status_id): 4

Comment: Добавил уникальный индекс, всё норм.